# Install Hadoop on Windows 7 fail to perform hadoop namenode –format

Tags: hadoop

I'm installing Hadoop for the first time and on Windows 7 using this blog:
http://blog.sqltrainer.com/2012/01/installing-and-configuring-apache.html

1. Installed Cygwin with the package openssh as a service
2. Downloaded and unpacked hadoop-1.0.4
3. Configured JAVA_HOME then checked:

   $ bin/hadoop version

   ```
   Hadoop 1.0.4 
   Subversion svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0 -r 1393290 
   Compiled by hortonfo on Wed Oct  3 05:13:58 UTC 2012 
   From source with checksum fe2baea87c4c81a2c505767f3f9b71f4
   ```
4. hdfs-site.xml content:

   ```
   <configuration>
   <property>
       <name>fs.default.name</name>
       <value>hdfs://localhost:47110</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
       <value>localhost:47111</value>
   </property>
   <property>
       <name>dfs.replication</name>
       <value>2</value>
   </property>
   </configuration>
   ```
5. mapred-site.xml content:

   ```
   <configuration>
   <property>
       <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
       <value>localhost:8021</value>
   </property>
   </configuration>
   ```
6. when I try to format the disk space I get:

   $ ./bin/hadoop namenode –format

   ```
   13/02/12 10:16:34 INFO namenode.NameNode: 
   STARTUP_MSG: /************************************************************ 
   STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode 
   STARTUP_MSG:   host = GUY-PC/192.168.1.5 
   STARTUP_MSG:   args = [▒format] 
   STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.0.4 
   STARTUP_MSG:   build = svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0 -r 1393290; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Wed Oct  3 05:13:58 UTC 2012
   ************************************************************/ 
   Usage: java NameNode [-format] | [-upgrade] | [-rollback] | [-finalize] | [-importCheckpoint] 13/02/12 10:16:34 INFO namenode.NameNode: 
   SHUTDOWN_MSG: /************************************************************ 
   SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at GUY-PC/192.168.1.5 
   ************************************************************/
   ```
7. when I try to start I get:

   $ bin/start-dfs.sh

   ```
   starting namenode, logging to /usr/local/hadoop/libexec/../logs/hadoop-guy-namenode-GUY-PC.out
   localhost: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1
   localhost: Connection closed by 127.0.0.1

   log  hadoop-guy-namenode-GUY-PC.log content:

   2013-02-12 10:21:27,101 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: 
   STARTUP_MSG:  /************************************************************ 
   STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode STARTUP_MSG:   host = GUY-PC/192.168.1.5 
   STARTUP_MSG:   args = [] 
   STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.0.4 
   STARTUP_MSG:   build = svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0 -r 1393290; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Wed Oct  3 05:13:58 UTC 2012
   ************************************************************/ 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,187 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,194 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered. 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,195 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s). 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,195 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,244 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered. 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,248 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered. 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,249 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source NameNode registered. 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,259 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type       = 32-bit 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,259 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2% max memory = 19.33375 MB 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,259 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^22 = 4194304 entries 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,259 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=4194304, actual=4194304 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,285 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=guy 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,285 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,285 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,288 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,288 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s) 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,356 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemStateMBean and NameNodeMXBean 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,370 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times  
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,372 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Storage directory C:\tmp\hadoop-guy\dfs\name does not exist. 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,373 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed. 
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: 
   Directory C:\tmp\hadoop-guy\dfs\name is in an inconsistent state: 
   storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.  at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:303)  at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:100)    at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:388)   at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:362)   at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:276)   at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:496)   at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1279)  at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1288) 
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,373 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode:
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: 
   Directory C:\tmp\hadoop-guy\dfs\name is in an inconsistent state: 
   storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.  at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:303)  at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:100)    at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:388)   at      
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:362)   at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:276)   at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:496)   at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1279)  at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1288)
   2013-02-12 10:21:27,374 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: 
   SHUTDOWN_MSG:  /************************************************************ 
   SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at GUY-PC/192.168.1.5
   ************************************************************/ 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,186 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: 
   STARTUP_MSG:  /************************************************************ 
   STARTUP_MSG: Starting NameNode 
   STARTUP_MSG:   host = GUY-PC/192.168.1.5 
   STARTUP_MSG:   args = [] 
   STARTUP_MSG:   version = 1.0.4 
   STARTUP_MSG:   build = https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0 -r 1393290; compiled by 'hortonfo' on Wed Oct  3 05:13:58 UTC 2012
   ************************************************************/ 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,270 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsConfig: loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,276 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source MetricsSystem,sub=Stats registered. 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,277 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled snapshot period at 10 second(s). 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,277 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSystemImpl: NameNode metrics system started 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,326 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source ugi registered. 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,330 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source jvm registered. 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,330 INFO org.apache.hadoop.metrics2.impl.MetricsSourceAdapter: MBean for source NameNode registered. 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,340 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: VM type       = 32-bit 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,341 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: 2% max memory = 19.33375 MB 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,341 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: capacity      = 2^22 = 4194304 entries 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,341 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.util.GSet: recommended=4194304, actual=4194304 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,367 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner=guy 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,367 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup=supergroup 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,367 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled=true 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,369 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=100 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,370 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: isAccessTokenEnabled=false accessKeyUpdateInterval=0 min(s), accessTokenLifetime=0 min(s) 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,436 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: Registered FSNamesystemStateMBean and NameNodeMXBean 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,450 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times  
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,452 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.Storage: Storage directory C:\tmp\hadoop-guy\dfs\name does not exist. 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,453 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem: FSNamesystem initialization failed. 
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: 
   Directory C:\tmp\hadoop-guy\dfs\name is in an inconsistent state: 
   storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.  at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:303)  at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:100)    at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:388)   at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:362)   at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:276)   at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:496)   at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1279)  at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1288) 
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,454 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode:
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.common.InconsistentFSStateException: 
   Directory C:\tmp\hadoop-guy\dfs\name is in an inconsistent state: 
   storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.  at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.recoverTransitionRead(FSImage.java:303)  at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSDirectory.loadFSImage(FSDirectory.java:100)    at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.initialize(FSNamesystem.java:388)   at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.<init>(FSNamesystem.java:362)   at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.initialize(NameNode.java:276)   at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.<init>(NameNode.java:496)   at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1279)  at
   org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1288)    
   2013-02-12 10:25:50,454 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode: 
   SHUTDOWN_MSG:  /************************************************************ 
   SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at GUY-PC/192.168.1.5
   ************************************************************/
   ```

When I search my exception in the net, I get the answer to run: `hadoop namenode –format` like I did in section 6.

Please help.

I solved the problem: 
I copied the command: `hadoop namenode –format` from an internet page.
When I simply wrote the character '-' with my keyboard it worked.

Comment: Hortonworks has released windows version of hadoop by modifying shell scripts wrappers by windows powershell scripts. You can directly install hadoop on your windows machine without any cygwin.

Use the following link for downloading the windows version :

http://s3.amazonaws.com/public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP-Win/1.1/Beta/HDP-WIN-1.1.0_BETA-hadoop.zip